# How to set rewrite rule in .htaccess for the 'pagename/id'?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have used the following code in .htaccess,

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^user-projects/([0-9]+)/?$ user-projects.php?uid=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This above code works for the url **mydomain.com/pagename** but if the url is like **mydomain.com/user-projects/1** it gives '*500 internal server error*'

Can anybody tell me where I am doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: why the question mark at the end?

Comment: I also used this `RewriteRule ^user-projects/([0-9]+)$ user-projects.php?uid=$1 [L,QSA]` but not worked

Comment: This is how I once started creating _pretty URLs_, but quickly changed my mind to putting the logic in a router and _MVC_ based framework.

Comment: Your first rewrite rule adds a .php extension to the request. Therefore the rewrite rule user-project/89 is first rewritten to user-project/89.php which skips the second rule

Comment: As Hofmann said, consider using a router such as http://toroweb.org/ or tinymvc to switch the routing logic to php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you get a 500 error is because the first rule that you apply is blindly adding a .php extension to whatever that isn't a file. So `/user-projects/1/` matches the first rule and gets a php extension tacked onto the end, and then the same thing happens again, and again.

You should either swap the order of the two rules, or make your php extension rule more precise:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+?)/?$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteCond ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

That checks first that if you add a .php to the end, it actually points to a file that exists.

Answer (score 0):

You have a forwardslash at the end of your rule, so it will match

`mydomain.com/user-projects/1/`

but not

`mydomain.com/user-projects/1`

You also don't need the question mark, so the correct rule would be

`RewriteRule ^user-projects/([0-9]+)$ user-projects.php?uid=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: I also used this RewriteRule ^user-projects/([0-9]+)$ user-projects.php?uid=$1 [L,QSA] but not worked

Comment: Can you check the Apache error log? That should tell you what is causing the 500 Error